# unable to click on Image Button

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

[image]

how do i click on the mage button
i tried with xpath and id below are the mentioned code that i had tried
    driver.findElementById("btn_google").click();
//      driver.findElementByName("Login with Google+").click();
        //driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Login with Google+',@resource-id,'btn_google']").click();
    //  driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'btn_google') and @content-desc,'Login with Google+']").click();

```
//  driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageButton' and @resource-id='btn_google']").click();

    //driver.findElementByName("Login with Google+").click();;
     WebElement element=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageButton' and @resource-id='btn_google']");
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.longPress(element).release().perform();

    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desct='Login with Google+']")).click();
```

//      WebElement googlebutton= driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@resource-id='com.zipgo.customer:id/btn_google']");
//      googlebutton.click();

Comment: Your last xpath seems to be correct. Just make sure that your app's screen loads completely before you execute the command to find the ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find the `id` of that imagebutton like:

```
googleImageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.googleImageButton);
```

And now you can call a listener method for any operation, for eg:

```
googleImageButton.setOnClickListener(googleImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //action
            }
        });)
```

Comment: this is what the coders do when u build a native app,from the testers point of view i cannot click that bimage button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
driver.findElementByXpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@index='0']").click();
```